# Resumable upload returns null and Refused to set unsafe header "content-length"

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm writing a service in ionic angular to upload/download images on a google drive via a service account.

So far the token is ok, but as soon as I try an upload with `uploadType=resumable`, it always returns `NULL`.

According to the google REST API doc, it's mandatory to set the Content-Length header, but when I do, I get this message:

> 'Refused to set unsafe header content-length'

I tried to remove the content-length and it had the same result.

```
let headers = { 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.lsGAPItoken['access_token'],
        'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
        'content-length': this.getFileSize(imgData,FILE_SIZE_UNIT.BYTES).toString(),        
        'X-Upload-Content-Length': this.getFileSize(imgData,FILE_SIZE_UNIT.BYTES).toString(),
        'X-Upload-Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
    }
};

null
```